# What is a somewhat secure way of generating a 64 bit signature?

Tags: security, language-agnostic, signature

I would like to [sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) a device, and I have 64 bits to store my signature in the device. This device has a MAC address and some other details (about 30 bytes worth) I can mangle to create my signature.

If possible, I would like the method to be one-way, so that I can verify that the signature is valid without knowing how to create a valid signature. Most public-private keys have this feature but they generate signatures that are 48 bytes long (I only have 8 bytes).

Implementation in Python is a plus.

Thanks

**EDIT**:
 Thanks for the advice everyone. It sounds like there is no *secure* way to do this, only a way that is moderately inconvenient to attackers. I'll probably use a cryptographic hash combined with secret bit-shuffling. This will be as secure as any other link in my (very weak) 'security'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hash functions and digital signatures are **very** different things.

The size of a digital signature depends on the underlying hash function and the key length. So in theory, you can create an RSA implementation that generates 64-bit signatures, but that'd be an extremely weak signature.

For smaller key lengths, you might want to look at elliptic curve cryptography.

**EDIT:** Yes, I'm a cryptographer.

**EDIT 2:** Yet if you only need a hash function, you can look at elf64 or RIPEMD-64 as Fernando Miguélez suggested.

**EDIT 3:** Doing the math, you'd need to use 16-bit keys in ECC to generate 64-bit signatures, which is very weak. For ECC, anything less than 128 bits can be considered weak. For RSA this is 1024 bits.

Comment: If it is that weak, is it worth using a standard algorithm at all? Should I just go the hash and scramble method and hope that security by obscurity saves the day?

Comment: Security by obscurity *never* works. First thing I learned in college. =)

Comment: Although 16-bit security is no security at all.

Answer (score 3):

Basically what you need is a 64-bit [cryptographic hash funcion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions), such as Ripemd-64 or elf-64. Then you encrypt the hash with a cryptographic method and you got a 64 bit signature. The only problem is, from the point of view of a non-cryptoanalyst, that 64 bit offers a much weaker signature than typical over-128 bit hash. Nonetheless it could still be suitable for your application.

Comment: Yeah, it is a pretty weak signature. We are happy to live with "it is harder to crack the signature than to crack something else". Any suggestions for the cryptographic method? Can I use something "Off the shelf?"

Comment: I would use RSA. There are various RSA implementations for Python out there, including a pure-python one (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rsa)

Comment: I have been looking around to find a suitable encryption method that gives the required output of 64 bits but it is not an easy task. Surely because such a weak encryption algorithm is more useless. What about using sth secret along with hash computing method?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a standard hashing function (MD5 SHA1) and only use the first or last 30 bytes.
The number of bytes a hashing function generates is fairly arbitrary - it's obviously a trade off between space and uniqueness. There is nothing special about the lenght of the signature they use.

Edit - sorry I was thinking that MD5 returned 32bytes- it actaulyl returns 16bytes but is ussually written as 32hex digits.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it is very easy for someone else to figure out which hashing algorithm I used and create their own signatures. I'm considering a standard hash followed by bit shuffling but it is symmetrical (to test the signature is to create the signature)

Comment: You _could_ use keyed hashing, that way the secret is with you. So, HMAC-MD5 or HMAC-SHA1, possibly truncated. I don't know about the security of this truncation, mind you.

Comment: Of course, keyed hashing means that the key used to sign needs to be with the verifier too (symmetric). Oh well. Maybe there is a way to do asymmetric keyed hashing. :-P

Comment: Keyed hashing is the best I can come up with, without trying to re-implement DSA (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm) with very small keys.